# is there anyway to make Volume 0% in safari browser using react/javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, mobile-browser, dailyco

I am building a react app. its using react and daily.co for video calls. Can someone suggest me a way to control volume and make it 0% if needed to mute participants using JavaScript AND REACT .
kindly include a code example for more clarity.

I googled a number of libraries but im not sure which one i should use to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control system volume, you cannot.
Javascript can control `video` or `audio` on its site.
For example:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.2;
```

Which values:

```
1.0 is highest volume (100%. This is default)
0.5 is half volume (50%)
0.0 is silent (same as mute)
```

See more: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp)

To do the same in `ReactJS` you can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to reference to `video/audio` you want to control and do the same above